# How to convert kernel to matrix notation?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, convolution, bicubic

I'm trying to understand the bicubic convolution algorithm and haven't been able to understand how the kernel given as a piece wide function,

[image: kernel given as a piecewise function]

is turned into this matrix:

[image: this matrix]

I understand to arrive at the matrix a was set to -0.5.  No matter how I look at it I can't arrive at the non-symmetric matrix shown.

I've looked through the [paper by Keys](http://www.ncorr.com/download/publications/keysbicubic.pdf), but he does not expand into matrix notation and I've struggled with how to get there.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing your question is pure math and not related to programming. It would be better to ask it on math site

Comment: @Vega I know this algorithm is very strongly tied to digital image processing and thought it's in the realm of programming.  Do you think on a pure math board, or something else?

Comment: I would recommend asking the question here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found and understood where Keys describes the process.  You can follow along from top to bottom in the image below, but the most important bit to note is Equation 7.
[image: Keys interpolation kernel]

All of the values within the matrix come from the coefficients of the c-terms.  The first row of the matrix corresponds to the coefficients of the constant terms, and the first column corresponds to the c_j-1 terms.  This can be seen by comparing the figure below to Equation 7's coefficients:
[image: matrix explanation]

I was able to use this understanding to implement the cubic convolution method to interpolate a surface for which I was able to tune the value of a in order to see the response.  I'm happy to help expand on this if anything is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 to see the relation is to multiply the function W(x) with the sampled input data f[n] for a given shift t. This gives 5 weights multiplying to 5 input samples, and added together to form an output sample p(t).

The matrix used to compute p(t) is not symmetric because, for any shift t that is not 0, the weights applied to the samples are not symmetric either. You can see this by writing out W(t+i), which are the weights applied to the 5 samples around the output position t (i in [-2,2]).